# TableView Sections iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with dates for sections. I want to have each section have the correct amount of rows based on how many items fall under the date.

To do this I created an `NSMutableDictionary` that uses the date as a key and has arrays of objects for the value. I have verified that my Dictionary gets populated, but in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method my Dictionary returns **0** for the length of every key. Why is this happening? Does `numberOfRowsInSection` get called before the `viewDidLoad` method?

Here is my `numberOfRowsInSection` method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [[itemsByDate objectForKey:[datesDB objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}
```

Here is how I populate my `NSMutableDictionary` in my `viewDidLoad` method

```
 [itemsByDate setValue:items forKey:[datesDB objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: just try reloadTable in viewDidAppear: method.. :)

Comment: Confirmed about memory has been allocated to NSMutableDictionary too.

Comment: I am new to iPhone development, how would I call reloadTable? Would I need to have a reference to my tableView ?

Comment: What is inside datesDB? is it NSDate or NSString?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be your problem solved ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      /// alloc this dictionary here
      ///retain dictionary after add data. 
      [itemByDate retain];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [yourtableView reloadData];
}
```

:)

Comment: I am using a normal ViewController, so I cannot call self.tableView, do I need to make a reference to it?

Comment: @JamesFazio try my Updated answer

Comment: I am using ARC so the retain method is not available.

Answer (score 0):

the mistake i usually make when working with tableView is I forget to allocate memory for the dictionary/array which is source for my tableview.

It may sound silly. Could you verify the same?

Comment: Yes I have allocated memory for both, but now it seems to be magically working.